# How to keep an __autoreleasing address as a strong property in a class?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, c, pointers

How can I make the address of a variable a strong property in an `NSObject`? I have a class called `SCPFMessageThreadQuery` which is alloc-inited by passing the address of an `SCPFMessageThread` variable.

```
@interface SCPFMessageThreadQuery ()

// This declaration seems correct.
@property (nonatomic) SCPFMessageThread *__strong *thread;

- (id)initWithRootMessage:(SCPFMessage *)root threadAddress:(SCPFMessageThread **)address;

@end

@implementation SCPFMessageThreadQuery

// Xcode somehow makes the ownership type __autoreleasing here during autocompletion.
- (id)initWithRootMessage:(SCPFMessage *)root threadAddress:(SCPFMessageThread *__autoreleasing *)address
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _root = root;

        // ERROR HERE. Xcode complains about changing the ownership of address.
        _thread = address;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

The error I'm getting is this:

> Assigning 'SCPFMessageThread *__autoreleasing *' to 'SCPFMessageThread *__strong *' changes retain/release properties of pointer

I plan to use this class in the following manner from my view controller:

```
SCPFMessageThread *thread = self.thread; // self.thread can be nil
SCPFMessageThreadQuery *query = [[SCPFMessageThreadQuery alloc]
    initWithRootMessage:self.rootMessage threadAddress:&thread];
```

I really need to pass the address here. I'll be making multiple calls to our API just to complete the information for a single object (`SCPFMessageThread`) in the app's code. Please don't ask me why the API doesn't do the JOIN itself instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the problem:

```
@interface AppDelegate ()
@property NSString * __strong * ivar;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
- (void)storeIndirect:(NSString * __autoreleasing *)par
{
  id xpar = *par;
  _ivar = &xpar;
}
@end
```

With the dereference you have a pointer to a retainable object. Only these (and *not* "pointer to pointer to a retainable object") are subject of ARC. Therefore the object `xpar` points to is retained – and released at the end of the method.

Of course you could store `xpar` into a property to hold it. But this makes it obvious that the whole code is useless: The double indirection would be lost in ARC. ARC cares about the objects behind a pointer, if it is a retainable object. Your pointer points to a C pointer, which is not a retainable object.

I do not think that there is a simple solution. (However you could use `CFRetain()` et al., if you do not care about the more or less theoretical `CFRetain()` is for CF objects problem.)

Even you confirmed it explicitly: Why do you need an extra level of indirect? If you really, really need it, think about an extra object in the middle:

```
@interface NSStringRetainableReference
@property NSString *string;
@end

@implementation
@end
```

Pass an instance object of this class as argument. Then you have a pointer to a retainable object and another level of indirection. But in this case it is built up from an object.

Comment: "Your pointer points to a C pointer, which is not a retainable object." Remembering that by heart now.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `__autoreleasing` storage for anything except local variables. Autorelease is a per-thread behavior. It's not safe to share `__autoreleasing` storage across threads or across stack frames that might pop autorelease pools.

Parameters of type `SomeObject **` are `__autoreleasing` by default. You can change your method declaration so it works with strong variables instead. Then you could use it directly with your strong property's ivar:

```
- (id)initWithRootMessage:(SCPFMessage *)root threadAddress:(SCPFMessageThread * __strong *)address
```

Note that when you take the address of an ivar or a local variable ARC does nothing to ensure that the containing object or stack frame lives as long as you need it to live.

Comment: +1 Another "solution" to show that there is no simple solution, but a requirement breaking the limits ARC can handle.